# upload_url for GitHub's upload-release-asset action when the trigger is a release?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to create a GitHub Action that is triggered when a release is published and will build my project and upload certain artefacts as release assets. The only examples I can find rely on using the `create-release` action, which fails as the release has already been created. My workflow file is like so:

```yaml
name: Build for Release

on:
  release:
    types: [published]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
    - name: Build
      run: ...
      
    - name: Zip Asset
      run: ...

    - name: Upload Release Asset
      uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      with:
        upload_url: ${{ ???? What Goes Here ???? }}
        asset_path: build/MyProject.zip
        asset_name: MyProject.zip
        asset_content_type: application/zip
```

My tags will be `v0.1.0`, `v0.1.1`, `v0.2.0` etc and the release name matches these.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access it on the event data in the `github` context:

```
- name: Upload Release Asset
  uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
  env:
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  with:
    upload_url: ${{ github.event.release.upload_url }}
```

See also [Example data for the `release` event](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#release).